# poor quality images in html2canvas using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html2canvas

I am creating a image on html2canvas but i get the poor resolution, 
This is code:

```js
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    },
    width: 500,
    height: 500
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
  <img width="128" height="128" src="1.png" alt="The Scream">
</div>
<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
<script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="canvas2image.js"></script>
```

Comment: code is here:                                                <div id="target">
<img  width="128" height="128" src="1.png" alt="The Scream">
</div>

<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>

<script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="canvas2image.js"></script>
<script>

 
  window.takeScreenShot = function() {
   
 
  

    html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"),
  {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
  
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  
   
        },
        width:500,
        height:500
    });
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You have image of size `128x128` and you try to resize it to `500x500`. It will reduce quality of origin image.